# How to get time left using command line during initial block download?

Tags: synchronization, bitcoin-cli

When using GUI version of Bitcoin Core, time left before initial block download has completed is displayed.

Using `bitcoin-cli`, one can see `verificationprogress`, but is there a way to get time left estimate?

Thanks for helping out!